# binary search to find the index of an item which is inside a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list containing dictionaries:

```
array =  [
    {"name": "Earth", "Density": 5.427},
    {"name": "Mars", "Density": 5.513},
    {"name": "Venus", "Density": 5.204},
]
element = input("What planet are you looking for? ")
```

The function should return the index of an item(planet in this case) or -1 if it doesn't exist.

```
F.e | For input= Earth, expected output would be: 0
For input = Venus, expected output: 2
```

The `binary search` is a must-have in this task.

```
My code gives TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'dict
```

My code:

```
array =  [
    {"name": "Earth", "Density": 5.427},
    {"name": "Mars", "Density": 5.513},
    {"name": "Venus", "Density": 5.204},
]
element = input("What planet are you looking for? ")

def DeletePlanet(array, element):
    mid = 0
    start = 0
    end = len(array)
    step = 0

    while start <= end:
        step = step + 1
        mid = (start + end) // 2

        if element == array[mid]:
            return mid

        if element < array[mid]:
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return -1


print(DeletePlanet(array, element))
```

Comment: `binary search` just work when array is sorted.I don't think your array is sorted.

Comment: It should be sorted by name

Comment: If so, try `array[mid]["name"]`.You're comparing `str` and `dict`.

Comment: Thanks! works well

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Name" try to replace it with Integer and sort it accordingly and then do your binary search on it...